# что возвращает return this?

Tags: java

```
public static class Builder {

    public Builder() {
        this.headers = new TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        this.parameters = new TreeMap();
        this.serverPort = 80;
    }

    public DefaultSavedRequest.Builder setCookies(List<SavedCookie> cookies) {
        this.cookies = cookies;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Ссылку на сам объект.

Comment: Экземпляр класса в котором он был вызван.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возвращается ссылка на себя. Этот "шаблон"  позволяет писать такой код:

```
Builder builder = new Builder().setCookies(...).setShmookies(...).setSomethingElse(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

Возвращается ссылка на текущий экземпляр объекта.

Это такой шаблон - [Fluent Interface](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Приведу цитату:

> Текучий интерфейс хорош тем, что упрощается множественный вызов
>   методов одного объекта. Обычно это реализуется использованием цепочки
>   методов, передающих контекст вызова следующему звену
>
> Такой стиль косвенно полезен повышением наглядности и интуитивности
>   кода. Однако может весьма пагубно сказаться на отладке, если цепочка
>   действует как одно выражение, куда отладчик не всегда может установить
>   промежуточную точку останова.

——

Вот что пишет про это господин [Фаулер](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)